# Combine two uneven lists in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have 2 list. One looks like

```
['jim', 'bob', 'mike', 'kim', 'Alex']
```

and the other looks like

```
['YES', 'YES', 'YES', 'YES', 'YES', 'YES', 'YES', 'YES', 'YES', 'YES', 'YES', 'YES', 'YES', 'YES', 'YES', 'YES', 'YES', 'YES', 'NO', 'NO', 'NO', 'NO', 'NO', 'NO', 'NO', 'NO', 'YES', 'NO', 'YES', 'NO']
```

Each name in list 1 corresponds to the first 6 items in list 2. So jim='YES', 'YES', 'YES', 'YES', 'YES', 'YES' and Alex='NO', 'NO', 'YES', 'NO', 'YES', 'NO'. Is there a way to merge these 2 lists into a dict ?

I was going to write a function like

```
def people():
    List1[0]=List2[0:6]
```

but that then mutates List1. I tried

```
dict(List1[0]: List2[0:6])
```

but get an error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a dict comprehension:

`{x: l2[6*i:6*(i+1)] for i,x in enumerate(l1)}`

If you want the horrible itertools version, which someone is bound to post sooner or later, it will look something like `dict(zip(l1, itertools.izip_longest(*[iter(l2)]*6)))`  ...blergh.

Comment: the dict comprehension is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Try `d = {List1[0] : List2[0:6]}` instead. You're trying to call the `dict` constructor with `:` syntax, but need to use `{}` to do this.